# Format Conversion happening for date but don't know why?

Tags: wpf, xml, xaml, datetime, datepicker

I am facing a strange problem. At first, when i insert a record in XML containing a date property which is binded to a DatePicker in XAML. The Element is in this form **2011-01-22T00:00:00**

Then there is a update page, which is filled with the values read from XML. I am reading date like this **Date = DateTime.Parse(record.Element("Date").Value;**

Now when i click update, and replace the date value like this **record.Element("Date").Value = Date**. The format Changes and Date element is like this **22-01-2011 00:00:00**

Comment: So what is it you want to know?

Comment: well i need to know, is this is supposed to happen ?? 
Because of this format change, i am not able to use this code **Date = record.Element("Date") != null && !record.Element("Date").Nodes().Any() ? null : (DateTime?)record.Element("Date")**
A formatException is thrown saying "String is not in correct Date Format".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for this format Conversion. Actually at first i am directly inserting the date into xml like this `doc.Element("root").Add(new XElement("Date", dt)))` but while updation, the date is first converted to string and then updated/added to XML.

***Conclusion***

- Direct Insertion of DateTime into XML
  has the **SortableDateTimePattern**
  (based on ISO 8601) using local time;
  with this format pattern, the
  formatting or parsing operation
  always uses the invariant culture
- While Insertion of
  DateTime.ToString() Converts the
  value of DateTime object to its
  equivalent string representation.
  (Overrides ValueType ..::.ToString
  ()()().)

Thank you all.